# Reference for De Giorgi-Nash-Moser theory

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, parabolic-pde, regularity

I am interested in Holder regularity for equations of the form
$$u_t - div A(x,t) \nabla u = 0$$ where $A(x,t)$ is bounded, measurable and elliptic.

This was proved in the seminal paper of John Nash and later on by J. Moser.

I am looking for references where Ennio De Giorgi's methods are implemented to obtain the same regularity estimates.

Comment: You may enjoy reading De Giorgi's original paper (which only deals with the elliptic case, though). To get an English translation of his paper just google "Ennio De Giorgi : selected papers"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof of Harnack's inequality using De Giorgi method has a great flexibility and it can be exteneded even to doubling metric measure spaces that support Poincaré inequalities.

The elliptic case has been treated in:

J. Kinnunen, N. Shanmugalingam, [Regularity of quasi-minimizers on metric spaces](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002290100193). *Manuscripta Math.* 105 (2001), 401–423.
([MathScNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1856619).)

The parabolic case has been treated in:

J. Kinnunen, N. Marola, M. Miranda, Jr., F. Paronetto,
[Harnack's inequality for parabolic De Giorgi classes in metric spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5356).
*Adv. Differential Equations* 17 (2012), 801–832. 
([MathScNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=349676&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=25&mx-pid=2985675).)

There are many other related results. Just search references and citations  of these two paper in MathSciNet.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the book of Emmanuele Dibenedetto, which deals with the operators (nonlinear) with divergence form. This book contains also a large reference, maybe you need it.

Degenerate Parabolic Equations